# Vaadin Calendar: How to display another atrribute on Event cell

Tags: java, javascript, calendar, vaadin

I want to display another attributes on vaadin calendar's event block. But by default it only display the Event caption, you can see demo from this link: http://demo.vaadin.com/calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to either extend `com.vaadin.addon.calendar.event.BasicEventProvider` or implement `com.vaadin.addon.calendar.event.CalendarEventProvider`.

If you choose to extend `BasicEventProvider`, you can just override its `addEvent` method like so:

```
@Override
public void addEvent(BasicEvent event) {
    event.setCaption("My custom caption");
    super.addEvent(event);
}
```

If you want more control over your events and the event provider, I recommend you create your own event provider that implements `CalendarEventProvider`. If the event has to contain more data than just caption, description and duration, you probably should create your own event class by extending `com.vaadin.addon.calendar.event.BasicEvent`.

When you have a custom event provider, you'll have to call `myCalendar.setEventProvider(myEventProvider);`

There's also a good article about this in the [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/calendar.eventprovider.html).